# PHP/Wordpress - how to make a complete condition

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, fetch

I am trying something here, I want to make a condition that allows me to fetch an info from a row in a Mysql if the page title is the same with a value from table "names"/column "lastname". Here I had made a table "names"
The "firstname" column would be unique in this table.

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
|      id | firstname | lastname |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | John      |   Smith  |
|       2 | Jane      |   Smith  |
|       3 | Jimbo     |   Jones  |
|       4 | Andy      |   Smith  |
|       7 | Chris     |   Jones  |
|      45 | Anna      |   Bell   |
|      44 | Jimmy     |   Carr   |
|      43 | Albert    |   Smith  |
|      47 | Johnna    |   Doe    |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

If the page name is equal to "Jimbo" than display "Jones" else error text (but still showing) or so. I don't know if this way good is while I don't have any ideeas anymore.
The code that i am using so far:

```
<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>
```

- for fetching the title -

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT lastname FROM names WHERE id = '2'");
if (!$result) {
echo 'error:bla ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 2
echo $row[1]; // 
?>
```

- For fetching the row -

In Wordpress I am using PHP code for posts and pages (I can make a shortcode).

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM names WHERE id='2' ");
if($result){
  echo $result->lastname;
}
```

Comment: cool but i want it so that (from "firstname" column) the code searches and when the page title equals one of the unique "firstname" values than show the "lastname" from the same row.